# SVG image pattern position, different behaviour in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, modernizr, snap.svg

I'm using this code with Snap.svg to create a pattern and then fill a path:

```
var s = Snap("#mysvg");
pattern = s.image(imgUrl, myX, myY, 200, 160).toPattern(myX, myY, 200, 160);
var frontHex = s.path(myPath).attr({
    fill: pattern
});
```

and the output is something like:

```
<svg id="mysvg">
<defs>
<pattern x="myX" y="myY" width="200" height="160" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="Si2mwvzou6" viewBox="myX myY 200 160">
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="imgUrl" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="myX" y="myY" width="200" height="160"></image>
</pattern>
</defs>

<path d="myPath" fill="url('#Si2mwvzou6')"></path>
</svg>
```

The problem is that IE seems to work differently with pattern elements and in order to show the image in the right position I have to set the x and y of the image element always equals to 0.

```
pattern = s.image(imgUrl, 0, 0, 200, 160).toPattern(x, y, 200, 160);
```

output within the pattern element:

```
<image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="imgUrl" preserveAspectRatio="none meet" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="160"></image>
```

I thought to change the script when the client is using IE, but "Detect specific browsers" is not recommended and anyhow the user.agent trick doesn't work anymore: [IE compatibility guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff986088(v=vs.85).aspx) .

I never used Modernizr.
Maybe this problem can be solved with it through feature detection? How?

Snap.svg automatically adds patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" on pattern and preserveAspectRatio="none meet" on the image. There is something to do here maybe?

**Update**

I temporarily fixed the bug using this simple snippet:

```
var image = s.image(myUrl, x, y, 200, 160);
if(image.attr("preserveAspectRatio") === "none meet")
    image.attr({x: 0, y: 0});
```

It works for IE, Firefox and Chrome.
I leave the question open, in case there are better or more correct solutions.

Comment: I'm noticing just now that the "meet" value in preserveAspectRatio is added in IE, but not in Firefox and Chrome. I could try to fix the problem only when the "meet" value is founded, although I am a bit distrustful in doing it this way.

Comment: The `meet` value shouldn't have an effect when `none` is specified, according to the svg spec, see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute.

Comment: Yes I don't know why but, only when using IE, preserveAspectRatio="none meet" is autogenerated instead of just "none". So I exploit this different output to know when to fix the pattern images coordinates accordingly.